# Using snackbar.isShown() in Android

Tags: android, snackbar

I want to use the snackbar in Android under API 22. However I can't use mSnackbar.ishown() as it is available in API 23. I need to compile the project under 22. What are the replacements method could I use under API 22?

```
    if (mSnackbar != null && mSnackbar.isShown()) {
             mSnackbar.dismiss();
            }
        }

      @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            if (mSnackbar == null || !mSnackbar.isShown()){
            mSnackbar = Snackbar.make(mCoordinatorLayout, R.string.snackbar_connection_failed, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                mSnackbar.setAction(R.string.snackbar_connection_failed_action, new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
                    }
                })
                        .show();
```

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0' add this in your gradle

Comment: revert back if it works or not

Comment: You can also use toast on non supported devices, you can also customize toast by extending it and put buttons and images.

Comment: check [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) for design-support-library

Comment: Ok thanks.. 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0' is already added to gradle but just one piece of code is requiring using of mSnackbar.isShown() which is only available in API level 23.  Maybe using toasts may be best I guess

Answer (score 5):

Use the latest Design support lib an it will be available:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23+'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Answer by @oberflansch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34261219/3485152) is correct.. use updated library.

And there is one easier workaround also:

Use `callback` on the snackbar to check when it is closed or shown.. and modify its tracking **boolean variable**